# Safe access to my home network subversion repository

Tags: security, home-networking, firewall, svn

I have a subversion server setup on my home network (windows).

I'd like to open a port in my router/firewall and allow access to it from the net. What do I need to do to make sure I don't put both my svn repo at risk and put at risk the rest of the network?

Comment: Unix or Windows?

Comment: Pretty much the best thing to do is use encryption.

Comment: right, it's a windows box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/)?

It's free and *really* nice. It sets up SSL access for you and everything.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried sharing out my SVN repository via svnserve+SSH (before moving to git). Works fine and it's secure. *Svnserve is a lightweight stand-alone server which uses a custom protocol over an ordinary TCP/IP connection which ships every copy of Subversion.*

Here's the Unix way, [Appendix G. Securing Svnserve using SSH](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-ssh-howto.html),

and here's the Windows way, [Svnserve Based Server Chapter 3. The Repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html)

Comment: I've not tried setting up svnserve on Windows so I can't verify if it works. I guess it should.

Answer (score 0):

GeneQ's answer is right.

But if you paranoic, then you create VPN/SSH connection to your home network.